# Auto-label sent messages in Gmail/Mail.app in OS X

Tags: gmail, imap, apple-mail

I'm using Gmail via IMAP in Mail.app in OS X. I've set up a number of labels in Gmail, and file incoming messages into the corresponding 'folders' in Mail.app, either automatically using Gmail's filters, or manually using Mail Act-On rules I have set up.

When I view my labels in the Gmail web interface, I can see complete conversations. For example, if I add a label to an incoming message, and then reply to that message, I can see both the original and the reply when I view the conversation in the label's message list.

However, in Mail.app the reply is not visible in the corresponding mailbox: only the incoming message is there. I can obviously copy my message from the Sent folder to the label's folder, but remembering to do that by hand is a pain. I know I can always view complete conversations in All Mail, but they're much easier to find in the label folders.

This question is similar to [an older one](https://superuser.com/questions/136338/in-mail-app-how-do-i-automatically-move-the-reply-to-the-original-emails-folder/153302#153302) on this site.